# When click then it will display the specific content

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML

```
<div class="view-content">
   <table class="views-table cols-10" style="font-size: 12px;">
     <thead>
       <tbody>       
          <tr class="even" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
              <td class="views-field views-field-title" style="background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248); color: black;">
                   <b>Is there any fees charged to lodge the complaint?</b>
                   <p style="font-size: 12px; display: none;"> 
              </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd" style="background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);">
            <td class="views-field views-field-rownumber" style="background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248); color: black;"> 3 </td>
            <td class="views-field views-field-title" style="background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248); color: black;">
               <b>Can I lodge a complaint on behalf of another person?</b>
                     <p style="font-size: 12px; display: none;">
            </td>
       </tr>
```

and I add jquery function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.view-content').find('table tbody tr').each(function() {
        $(this).find('td.views-field-title p').hide();
        // alert($(this).html());
    });
})
```

The problem is when I add:

```
$('td.views-field-title b').click(function () { 
      $('td.views-field-title p').show();
})
```

it did not work,the action will display all the content of `<p></p>`
instead display `<p></p>` for selected `'td.views-field-title b'`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

That's happening because your `td.view-field-title p` selector matches all `<p>` elements in `<td class="view-field-title">` elements. I think you want to use [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to limit what you show:

```
$('td.views-field-title b').click(function () {
    $(this).next('p').show();
});
```

Be careful with this approach though, it is highly sensitive to the structure of your HTML. A better way would be to go back up to the `<td>` and then come down to the `<p>` using [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) and [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$('td.views-field-title b').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('td').find('p').show();
});
```

This is still sensitive to your HTML structure but less so.

And an example of the second approach (with HTML errors fixed): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/CBLtt/

---

If you want to have only one paragraph open at a time, then a simple modification to the click handler is all that is needed:

```
$('td.views-field-title b').click(function () {
    $('td.views-field-title p').hide();      // Hide them all.
    $(this).closest('td').find('p').show();  // Then show the one we want.
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/CBLtt/1/

Comment: let say when user click specific b content then it will hide the p that already display,can i do like this $('td.views-field-title b').click(function () { 
    $('.view-content').find('table tbody tr').each(function() {
        $(this).find('td.views-field-title p').hide();
    });
    $(this).next('p').show();
})

Comment: @syncrolord: I added an update for that, easier than trying to jam a bunch of code in a comment. The code in your comment looks about right though.